# Method after a ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I need to perform a method after the clicking of a JButton in a Java Project.
I'm making a client-server game and after the click of a button I need that the client/server start to wait untill the opponent perform a click. The problem is that at the end of the action listener code I start a loop end untill the opponent don't perform another click the jbutton stays clicked..

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     JButton o = (JButton)e.getSource();
     String name = o.getName().substring(3);
     Click(Integer.parseInt(name));
     if(isServer)
         ListenServer();
     else
         ListeClient();
}
```

ListenServer() and ListenClient() are two loop function... How can I call this methods AFTER the click??? Thanks and sorry for the bad english

Comment: Read about [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use threads and synchronization. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html for examples.